# run a jquery function onload and focus

Tags: jquery, focus, onload

I have a function :

```
function skillbar() {
    $('.skillbar').each(function(){
        var percent = $(this).attr('data-percent');
        $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').delay(400).animate({width:percent},1500);
    });
}
```

I want this function to be executed when the page is loaded. so I run it like this :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    skillbar();
});
```

but I also want this function to be run only when browser tab is focused.
I tried this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(window).focus(function(){
        skillbar();
    });
});
```

The problem is that, when I use `.focus();` when page is loaded, I have to switch browser tab once, and then it works.
It means I have to focus on window onload, but what if someone is on another browser tab ?

demo http://jsfiddle.net/sem847un/1/

Comment: I added a demo of what I mean if it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You need $(document).ready(function(){
This will initiate the function on load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
skillbar();
function skillbar() {
    $('.skillbar').each(function(){
        var percent = $(this).attr('data-percent');
        $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').delay(400).animate({width:percent},1500);
    });
}
});
```